# dhtmlxScheduler - ASP.net razor

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have added the dhtmlxScheduler event calender to my site and it works fine . i am just   having some trouble incorporating it into my sites design layout. My site was developed using ASP.Net and razor view engine. I use a _Layout.cshtml page to add a consistent design to all my pages  by adding the following code to the top of all pages " Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";"
The page i added to include the dhtmlScheduler event calendar is called Calender.cshtml. I have tried to include the _layout page in the Calendar.cshtml page but it didn't work so instead i just added the sites header and footer design to the Calendar.cshtml it works but the page still looks different from the other pages on the site , what i mean by this is all other pages have a centered page layout and the Calendar page seems to be align to the left. i will add to images to show the difference between the pages. I am just wondering has anyone added the dhtmlScheduler to their site and managed to include their sites layout design with the event calendar.

Code for Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@Page.Title</title>
<link href="~/Styles/Style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     
</head>
<body >
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Annual Leave Management System</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>


    <div id="footer">
      &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year Annual Leave Management System
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Code for the Calendar page:

```
@{

//Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Leave Calendar";   

}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
     <title>@Page.Title</title>
<link href="~/Styles/Style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>dhtmlxScheduler</title>
    <script src="@Href("~/Scripts/dhtmlxScheduler/dhtmlxscheduler.js")"></script>
    <script           src="@Href("~/Scripts/dhtmlxScheduler/ext/dhtmlxscheduler_dhx_terrace.js")"></script>
    <link href="@Href("~/Scripts/dhtmlxScheduler/dhtmlxscheduler_dhx_terrace.css")"   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

       <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function init() {
            scheduler.config.multi_day = true;

            scheduler.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
            scheduler.init('scheduler_here', new Date(2014, 3, 7), "month");

            scheduler.load("@Href("~/data.cshtml")");
            var dp = new dataProcessor("@Href("~/save.cshtml")");

            dp.init(scheduler);
            dp.setTransactionMode("POST", false);
            }
          </script>
          </head>
      <body onload="init();">

     <div id="header" style='width:80%;'>
      <h1>Annual Leave Management System</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:81%;  height:70%;'>


        <div class="dhx_cal_navline" >

            <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"> </div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"> </div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="dhx_cal_header">
          </div>
          <div class="dhx_cal_data">
          </div>

    </div>

<a href="@Href("~/Logout")">Log out</a>
<br/>
<a href="@Href("~/Home")">Home</a>
<br/>

    &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year Annual Leave Management System

    </body>

 </html>
```

Images:

page with _layout.cshtml included:

[image]

calendar page :

[image]